# Mock a Property in BaseClass

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking

I am trying to write some unit tests for an old system. 
consider that I have a base class and a service like this :

```
public class BaseService
    {
        [Dependency]
        public IBaseInterface _mybaseInterface { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyService : BaseService, IMyService 
    {
        private readonly ISomeOtherInterface _myOtherInterface;


        public MyService(ISomeOtherInterface myOtherInterface)
        {
            _myOtherInterface = myOtherInterface; 
        }
    }

 public class MyOtherService 
        {
            private readonly IMyService _myservice;


            public MyService(IMyService myservice)
            {
                  _myservice = myservice
            }
        }
```

Question 1: 
I am writing test for the MyOtherService class and I have to mock the IMyservice but I dont know how can I mock the interfaces in the base clas.

Question 2: 
does converting the injection of the BaseService to constructor injection help me to mock the Myservice class dependencies ?

Comment: I am still unclear on what you are asking based on the current example. What is the problem.

Comment: I asked two questions 1) is there any way for me to mock that interface in MyService class ?, means how can I mock the IBaseInterface when I am writing tests for the MyService calss. And the question is my own idea and I wanted to know its correct or not

Comment: The base property is public so you can simple mock the interface in the test and set it on the instance.

Comment: sorry you are right I missed to say that consider that I am mocking the IMyService  for another class in that situation if I mock the IMyservice I just can see the methods of that interface and not the base properties. (I dont know how to edit my question here)

Comment: I found a way to edit my question.